# Accessing Sourceforge via SSH and saving password

Tags: svn, ssh, tortoisesvn, sourceforge

I have a SVN repo on sourceforge. Currently checkins are done via HTTPS but I want to switch to SVN+SSH. When I connect via SVN+SSH I will asked each time for the password. I know that there is the [option to work](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-ssh-create-keys.html) with public keys. But this just works when I am the server admin, right? How can I store the password?

By the way, I want to switch to SSH because it should be faster. Is this right?

Comment: Sorry I am pretty new to this topic and spend quite some time to search for answers.I can not find something how to get the public key for sourceforge.... As far as I understand it without the public key I cannot connect to sourceforge.

Answer (score 4):

It might be a bit late, but I think this is what you are looking for:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/SSH%20keys

> To access our services via SSH, a user must be a project member
>   (developer), have any needed project permissions enabled for the type
>   of access desired, and have an SSH Client setup

Answer (score 4):

For googling purposes

(click on "Me" button) account->services-> ssh key.

In few minutes should be working.